# how to install varnish in wamp?

Tags: php, magento, drupal, wamp, varnish

how to install varnish in wamp environment?

now i'm optimizing projects that are based on magento and drupal,

all the module/extension available out there, that related to cache needs the varnish cache installed

i want to test all in local with wamp enviroment , even though the production server is lamp based

can you provide official guides or articles to install varnish?

Comment: May be [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishOnCygwinWindows) gives you direction

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this answers your question as I do not know how much do you want to use your current wamp environment, but with these tools you can create any virtual machine configuration you want:

> https://puphpet.com/

Also, if we are talking about Drupal, there is a tool specially for this:

> https://www.drupalvm.com/

I am using both for the development and I am very satisfied. You will need Virtual Box for those

> https://www.virtualbox.org/

It's all free.